# Remove string between 2 characters from text string

Tags: python, regex

I have text string like:

```
"abcd[e]yth[ac]ytwec"
```

I need just

```
"abcdythytwec"
```

What is the easiest way to do it using regex or otherwise in python? I am using `.split('[')` method which is cumbersome.

Comment: Is this a more general case? Is it possible there are more than two [e]'s?

Comment: Definitely. There may even be none.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
In [11]: re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '', 'abcd[e]yth[ac]ytwec')
Out[11]: 'abcdythytwec'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using re module:

`import re`

`re.sub(r'\[[^]]*\]', '', "abcd[e]yth[ac]ytwec")`