# How to remove text between 2 characters using query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have table with field called description which contains text like following

```
|Description                              |
|-----------------------------------------|
|This is a text <a>blah</a> <br/> <img /> |
|This is <b>second</b> <a>row</a>         |
```

I would like to remove everything between "**<**" and "**>**"

### Required Output

```
|Description                              |
|-----------------------------------------|
|This is a text blah                      |
|This is second row                       |
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this using MYSQL query. I cant currently use Stored procedure for the same as I don't have rights. I have requested for the access to use stored procedure but that will take some time and I have to finish this bit urgently.

Thanks.

**Update:** my question is similar to [Remove string between 2 characters from text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470142/remove-string-between-2-characters-from-text-string) but I want it to be done in MYSQL query.

Comment: You could probably do it with [regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Both of you, regex won't do it, since it only does matching, not replacement.

Comment: @slugonamission I dont want to update my table. I just want output to be modified.

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary - it's still impossible, I was meaning that it can't do replacement even at the select stage.

Comment: Alright after long research I didnt really find a way to solve it using query hence used Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't, you need a more advanced language like PHP. Your SQL query is not the place to be doing string manipulation.

Comment: You could do it using concatenation and substrings, but that would require you to know how many tags each field contained.

Answer (score 1):

How about REPLACE() using a wildcard to capture the unknown text between opening and closing brackets? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

if you use php as your server side language you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function to remove tags.I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

since this question is still in top google results, maybe the answer might help someone:

a quick function that replaces the content between two characters. It should work with words as well, but I haven't test it with words. For deleting in the following string:
"this is a [demo]"

the string between [ and ]  do:

select deletestr("this is a [demo]" ,'[',']');

and the function:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`replace_with_your_db`@`%` 
FUNCTION `deletestr` (`inputstr` TEXT CHARSET utf8, `fromstr` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8, `tostr` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
RETURN
replace(inputstr,substr(inputstr, locate(fromstr,inputstr),locate(tostr,inputstr)-locate(fromstr,inputstr)+length(tostr)),'')
```